# Pandas extract error: "Columns must be same length as key"

Tags: python, pandas

Im using Pandas to extract a sub-string from a column in a excel sheet
The regex has been tested multiple ways and does work
Error below:

[image: Error given in shell]

Says its found a match but get the same error over and over again

[image]

Whats happening

Comment: Data as images is not useful. Please provide a code in text that reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably capturing more than 1 group and all of those are returning another column. You can't assign multiple columns into a single column. Capture a single group with your regex or concatenate your result to your original dataframe. Don't assign it to a single column